# Is there something like CDN_FILECANCEL analogous to CDN_FILEOK for getting when the user chooses Cancel in GetOpenFileName()?

Tags: c, winapi, modal-dialog, comdlg32

For cross-platform parity reasons, my `GetOpenFileName()` specifies no owner and I explicitly disable all toplevel windows myself. The problem is re-enabling. [In order to re-enable these windows correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/27/81155.aspx), I need to re-enable them before the dialog closes.

In the case of the user choosing a file, this is no issue: I just check for `CDN_FILEOK` in the hook procedure. No issues, no messed-up focus.

How can I do the same, but for cancelling the dialog box?

I have tried `WM_DESTROY` in the hook procedure, but that runs after the dialog box has been hidden (too late). I have tried `WM_COMMAND`, but that doesn't seem to cover all cases. I'm not sure what other options I have.

I need to target Windows XP and newer for now; that also means no Common Item Dialogs. Thanks!

**Alternative**: if there was a way to do a callback-based `GetOpenFileName()` that returned control to **my** message loop, like on Mac OS X with `beginSheetModalForWindow:`, I could be able to specify a parent window and avoid this hack.

Comment: The obvious mistake you are making is helping too much.  The dialog already knows how to be modal without your help.  And knows how to do it right.

Comment: It does, but I cannot choose a /single/ modal owner. I would like it to be modal to all windows of the program, not just one of them. My message loop does a lot of extra stuff; I'd rather not have that stuff being overridden by `GetOpenFileName()`'s.

Comment: Clearly the rest of your code has to pretty messed up to break the contract of a dialog.  Surely starting from "my message loop does".  Nobody can see it.  Just stop doing that.

Comment: Agreed. `GetOpenFileName()` accepts an owner HWND for a reason. You really do need to use it the way it is intended to be used. Your message loop is obviously doing something it should not be doing if you have to circumvent the way the API is designed to be used.

Comment: I have two things: an override for WM_(SYS)KEYDOWN/UP for one of my custom window classes (one that doesn't support TranslateMessage) and one that allows tabbing between tabs and their children. https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/master/redo/uitask_windows.c#L11 I don't know what other options I have, apart from only allowing one toplevel window and requiring any others you want to open in this API to be dialog boxes. (Dialog modality is nonportable...)

Comment: Actually, now I wonder if what I am doing here could be done without using a custom message loop; the big thing is that I need to inhibit IsDialogMessage() if I handle a keypress in the "area" window class...

Comment: (if someone is still interested in answering tha tquesiton,i I moved the IsDialogMessage() to under notkey: in the code listed locally)

Comment: HansPassant, RemyLebeau - actually different idea - if I run the GetOpenFileName() in its own thread, with a specified owner window, I could still get events properly in my other windows with my regular message loop, right?

Comment: If you decide to build a cross-thread window hierarchy, make sure you understand the implications of calling [`AttachThreadInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx).

Comment: I'm aware. The idea here is simple: the new thread just calls GetOpenFileName() and returns; as a result, its parent window will be disabled anyway. Meanwhile, every other window in the system will continue to run with my customized message pump, and when GetOpenFileName() returns and the thread exits, (I hope, anyway, that) all control returns to the main thread.

Comment: Create a dummy hidden owner window and use that as the owner for the dialog. When the dummy owner is enabled, that's your change to enable all the other windows.

Comment: It's months late but I can say I'm doing what @RaymondChen suggested now. What I did earlier didn't work, but only now did I get to a point where I could rewrite; thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CDN notification when the dialog is canceled.  If the user presses the Cancel button, you could try intercepting the [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825.aspx) notification that it sends to the dialog, or even subclass the button itself.  But if the user cancels the dialog through other means (clicking the red X, pressing ESC, etc), you will likely have to catch the `WM_CLOSE` message instead.

Comment: No luck with either approach. I don't think the hook procedure is getting the BN_CLICKED; in fact, if I understand the documentation correctly, it's not even the dialog procedure for the whole open dialog, but rather for a subdialog... so now I wonder how my original question would even have worked...

Comment: You can subclass the dialog's HWND (or its parent HWND) directly to intercept those kind of messages.